# opt-in, the client can click several times on the confirmation link and sends the same mail a lot of times

Tags: email-validation

I implemented opt in. the issue is that when the confirmation mail arrives in the mailbox of the customer, the client can click several times on the confirmation link. And like this we receive repeatedly the same email from the same client.
The fact that the client sends the same mail a lot of times affects our IP reputation 
The message that we have in the confirmation mail is clear to click just once, but we still have clients who click several times.  Is there a code to block multiple clicks?

the confirm text : Please click here to confirm your subscription, 
`http://mysait/confirm.php?E=xmailx%40yahoo.com&C=d175b481e0f0253d191ff6005db53462`
and the cod from link is something like:

Thanks!

Comment: There's nothing you can do, but I don't see that this has any bearing on sending reputation. Why are you sending additional emails when your confirmation has already completed?

Comment: the client send emails, they click on the confirmation link for 3-4 times and they  send 3-4 emails in 2-3 seconds. instead receive a single mail receive more depending on how many times the customer clicks

Comment: Can you clarify - is this link on your site or in their message? If it's on your site, just keep track of the last time a message was sent to that address and don't send a message if it was in the last few seconds.

Comment: the link in on message i send to the client on mail

Comment: I don't really see your problem. When they click the link they will be switched to their browser immediately, they would have to make quite an effort to click that many times. Why can't you just ignore duplicates? It makes no difference to your confirmations.

Comment: is not that great effort. and it happens. The ip reputation is affects  when the client sends to me 4-5 emails in seconds

Comment: IP reputation is typically only applicable to senders, so why does this affect you? Which email clients open a browser link without bringing a browser to the front? Why are any emails generated at all after confirmation?

Comment: ip damage is undoubtedly.

Comment: You are making no sense at all. I don't see how or why your clients clicking the confirmation link are sending any email at all. If they are, you're doing something fundamentally wrong. How are you measuring your supposed IP damage?